# Created calendar view from SharePoint List, all items from the list show on a single day.

Tags: office-365

I am trying to display calendar data from an Outlook calendar into a SharePoint calendar. After manipulating the data into an Access database, I use Access's database tool to move the data to SharePoint, where a new list is created.

Creating a Calendar view is easy enough, except when I get to part where I need to tell the calendar where to look for Begin and End dates. Those drop downs only give the choice of "Created" or "Modified", which means all 145 entries in the list get placed on the day the list was created and/or modified.

How to I get to a place where I can choose from my start and end columns?

I am running Office 365. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DCarter

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the field that stores your event date, and make sure it's a date/time field. It probably came over as "single line of text", which would prevent it from being an option to be used for the calendar.

Comment: Yes. you're right. The date/time fields came over from Access as Short Text. Changing them in SharePoint messes up the event time. If verify them before I move the file to SP, it works. Thank you!